# Application hangs during rapid text drawing

Tags: ios, multithreading, uitableview, nsoperationqueue, terminal-emulator

I am working on terminal emulation app to connect to my unix servers through telnet, i am using tableview (one cell for the one text line). What troubles me is that when server sends enormous textual data in response to some command, that makes app less responsive (delays) to touch any button on screen or any gesture because drawing is in main thread which does not allow other process to work unless it finished.

What should be a perfect approach to resolve this, do i need OperationQueue, i don't know much about it.

I need something like when drawing is going on, i can smoothly interact with app (this can pause the drawing).

I think the same that the drawRect my be taking longer time, actually what i am doing in not with reloadData or ReloadTableCell, i have a mutable attributed string in the text line cell of tableview, and when text is need to be added to that cell, i just replace the characters in that mutable attributed string and call the setNeedsDisplay for cell that invokes the drawRect. In drawRect my code is as below-

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    _cursorView.frame = CGRectMake(([_delegate cursorXInTextLine:self] - 1 )* 6, 0, 6, 10);

    [self drawText:0 yPosition:0 canvasWidth:self.bounds.size.width canvasHeight:10];
}


- (void)drawText:(CGFloat)xPosition yPosition:(CGFloat)yPosition canvasWidth:(CGFloat)canvasWidth canvasHeight:(CGFloat)canvasHeight
{
    //Draw Text
    CGRect textRect = CGRectMake(xPosition, yPosition, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

    [self.textLineText drawInRect: textRect];
}
```

Other methods that do the textReplacement is as below-

```
-(void)initializeWithStringChar:(NSString*)charString
{
    NSInteger len = charString.length;

    while (len > 0) {

        //length can be displayed.
        NSInteger cutLength = totalCols - cursorX + 1;

        if (len < cutLength) {
            cutLength = len;
        }

        NSString *str = [charString substringToIndex:cutLength];
        [self placeTextInCurrentTextLine:str :YES :YES :YES];

        charString = [charString substringFromIndex:cutLength];
        len -= cutLength;
    }
}
-(void)placeTextInCurrentTextLine:(NSString *)text :(BOOL)needsToReplace :(BOOL)useCurrentCharAttrs :(BOOL)adjustCursor{

    TextLineCell *textLineCell = (TextLineCell *)[self.telnet_TableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:currentLineIndexPath];

    if (cursorX > totalCols) {
        if (self.autowrap == YES) {
            [self goNewLineAndResetCursor:YES];

            textLineCell = (TextLineCell *)[self.telnet_TableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:currentLineIndexPath];
        }
        else
            cursorX--;
    }

    NSAttributedString *attrText;

    if (useCurrentCharAttrs) {
        //Use current chars attributes
        attrText = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:text attributes:currentCharAttrDict];
    }
    else{
        //Use default chars attributes
        attrText = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:text attributes:defaultCharAttrDict];
    }

    NSMutableAttributedString *attrLineText = [telnet_ScreenData objectAtIndex:currentLineIndexPath.row];

    if (needsToReplace) {
        //Replace chars with existing
        [attrLineText replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(cursorX - 1, text.length) withAttributedString:attrText];
    }
    else{
        //Insert and shift chars
        [attrLineText insertAttributedString:attrText atIndex:cursorX - 1];

        //shift out the last characters
        attrLineText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithAttributedString:[attrLineText attributedSubstringFromRange:NSMakeRange(0, totalCols)]];
    }

    [telnet_ScreenData replaceObjectAtIndex:currentLineIndexPath.row withObject:attrLineText];

    if (adjustCursor) {
         cursorX = cursorX + (int)text.length;
    }

    if (textLineCell) {
        textLineCell.textLineText = attrLineText;

        [textLineCell setNeedsDisplay];
    }
    else{
        [_telnet_TableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:homeIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Revinder i am also facing same problem. I want to stop NSOperationQueue for a while.In NSOperationQueue have a 1 or more NSOperations.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: `placeTextInCurrentTextLine::::` (which is a poor name for a method) is directly editing table view cells by calling `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. That is forcing the system to create a cell that may not be on the screen (possibly even ejecting a cell that is in cache). If lots of cells are generated, this actually may force cells to be created that otherwise would never be needed. The datasource's job is to be passive and configure cells when they are requested.

When text comes in, you should figure out what text goes on what lines, and then call `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` to tell the table view that there is new data. You then wait for it to ask you for particular rows, and when it does, you configure a cell for it. You do not maintain a collection of table view cells. You just configure the one cell that you're asked for, ideally pulling an existing one off of the free list with `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`. At any given time, there should only be as many cells in existence as there are rows on the screen (perhaps plus a few for scrolling). Study [Populating a Dynamic Table View with Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH6-SW10) for details.

---

A tableview is an interesting solution. I would have gone with `UITextView`, since its' more designed to handle large text blocks. But who knows, a tableview might be a rather clever solution (and I can see how it might even work better than my way).

The main question for all performance problems is where the actual problem occurs. You need to start by running Instruments with the Time Profiler and see where you are spending your time. Then you can investigate how to improve that.

That said, there are several fairly obvious thing you may be doing incorrectly. First, you must manage table cell reuse correctly. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you should be fetching a previously used cell that has scrolled off the screen (using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`) and then simply reconfiguring it with your new data. You should *not* be creating a new cell in every call to `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. You should keep your cells as simple as possible (you probably only need a single `UILabel` that you modify the text of).

You must also be very careful to avoid calling `reloadData`. Since you're going to just keep adding to the end, you want to call `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`. This way `UITableView` doesn't have to recompute everything.

On the backend, if you're finding that parsing the incoming traffic into lines is expensive, you should definitely move your parsing off of the main queue. In principle, `NSOperationQueue` is the "highest abstraction" and usually it is good advice to use the highest abstraction available. That said, I've found that most people "get" dispatch queues much more easily than operation queues. Much of the operation queue API is based on a pre-GCD concurrency system, so much of the documentation covers topics that are seldom used today. I recommend reading the [Dispatch Queues section of the Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW1) to become familiar with them. Managing dispatch queues is a key and very common skill for iOS developers.

But step one, as always with performance, is to get comfortable with Instruments and make sure you know what's actually going on in your program.

Comment: Actually i have tried the core text drawing on view and then also used textview but there were restrictions-  the first approach does not allow to shift the drawn text above and can not have a wider view to support for commands that produces large line of text. the second approach was better but hangs when we try to add large text in textview at once. Then we end up using tableview, but it also hangs when large amount of text comes even i have limited the socket to receive 1024 bytes at once. 
So please suggest something that can be done in this scenario.

Comment: When you run Instruments, where does it say you are spending your time? Resolving performance issues almost always requires data first.

Comment: It spends most the time in drawrect for cell and in the method that checks and remove text lines when specified number of lines exceeds (Screen Buffer).

Comment: Well, that second one definitely sounds like where I would focus. And you should start looking into whether your drawRect: calls are too expensive (your cell is too complicated) or if you're invalidating cells too often (reloadData: for instance) and forcing too much redrawing.

Comment: Please see the edited part and suggest if anything that can be improved.

Comment: Hey please help me out.